# Dificuldade para calcular desenho de triangulo em java

Tags: java, loop, for, matemática

Eu tenho duas entradas, altura e base. E de acordo com os dados tenho que montar o triângulo.

Consegui fazer o cálculo baseado no tamanho da base, se a base for maior que a altura funciona, porém, se eu fizer o contrário (altura maior que a base) o algoritmo quebra, poderiam me ajudar?

```
int height = 10;
int base = 5;
double scale = base / height;
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < height; i++) {
    System.out.print("x");
    sum += scale;
    for (double j = 1; j < Math.round(sum); j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("x");
}
for (int k = 0; k < base; ++k) {
    System.out.print("x");
}
```

se a base for maior que a altura:

```
x x
x   x
x     x
x       x
x         x
x           x
x             x
x               x
x                 x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

se a altura for maior que a base:

```
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xxxxx
```

estou tendo dificuldade para montar a lógica para fazer o contrário, montar o triângulo com a altura maior que a base;

Comment: Boa noite. Se você inverter a ordem da divisão: base/height para height/base, você vai conseguir exibir o seu triângulo dessa forma: [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYt8b.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYt8b.png) Porém eu não sei se isso seria o Ideal para o algoritmo. Fazendo a inversão acima, você vai ver o mesmo resultado da imagem. Mas precisa ajustar o seu loop.

Comment: Na verdade, esse código só vai construir um triangulo certo somente quando a base for o dobro da altura, se for maior e nao for o dobro, vai montar com sobra na base.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16453675/5524514

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada. Vlw

Answer (score -4):

Boa noite amigo!
Consegui desta forma.
Troque o (Math.round) por "j < i" e
na ultima linha ponha um espaço no
System.out.print(" x");

[Acompanhe o comentário da imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Ltl.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).